# Two numbers for one enumerated item

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

Preferably using the [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) package, how can I create a list of this form?

```
(1), (2) First item
(3) Second item
(4) Third item
etc.
```

Comment: Are you going to reference the items as well?

Comment: Yes. I would like to be able to reference the numbers individually.

Comment: [Here is a start](https://pastebin.com/eJesxNXh).

Comment: This sort of breaks the format of any normal list.  What list features do you want to retain: hanging indentation, multiple paragraphs, nesting with other list environment, page breaking?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Indentation can be determined by the other list items. Multiple paragraphs and page breaking are essential. Nesting with other list environment is not currently needed but what would be the issue here?

Comment: @Werner Using your starting point, is there a way to have the label (1), (2) be flush with the left margin, i.e. `leftmargin=*`, and indent the first line to accommodate for the extra width without affecting subsequent lines of text of the same or other items?

Comment: Lists like enumerate use counters enumi, enumii, enumiii and enumiv depending on how deep they are nested.  The indentation is implemented using \leftskip and recalculated at the start of each list.  It is the nesting that makes lists complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the first item (and accompanying horizontal alignment) manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setref}[1]{\def\@currentlabel{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}, start=3, leftmargin=*]
  \item[] \hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelindent-\labelwidth-\labelsep+\itemindent}%
    \setref{(1)}\label{first-a}\setref{(2)}\label{first-b}%
    (1), (2) \hspace{\itemindent}First item
  \item \label{second} Second item
  \item Third item
  \item etc.
\end{enumerate}

See items~\ref{first-a} and~\ref{first-b}, or~\ref{second}.

\end{document}
```

We also set the reference manually via `\setref{<stuff>}`, after which one can use `\label` in the usual way. If [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is loaded, consider adding `\phantomsection` to appropriately mark the hyperlink to jump to.

Comment: Are you interested in referencing (1) or (2)?

Comment: Both if possible. If not then (1) is fine.

Comment: @Casimir: See the updated answer.

Comment: Very nice! `hyperref` is indeed loaded, thanks for the hint.